# Best Practice For Mobile View in Ruby On Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobile, responsive-design

Hi I am in this process of restyling a Rails application. I was wondering what the best practice is to making it mobile responsive.

Should I be using mobile.html.erb files with the mobile_fu gem?

Or would it be enough to just take a fluid template on bootstrap which will automaically render the menu etc. differently using JQuery and Javascript, I think this way would be more straight forward?

What are peoples ideas on the best approach. Also if I use mobile.erb files and I want an application.mobile.erb file do I need to make changes inside the application controller?

Comment: Are you planning to support full version or just for mobile?

Comment: Full version, the application will be used on desktop and mobile devices

Comment: I have created same project with jQuery and jQuery-mobile, and think this was a good decision, now the application is more flexible and easy to extend

Comment: Thanks, I look into jQuery-mobile, I am also reading about css3 media queries at the moment I suppose there is no right/wrong way just different ways of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going for a fully functional app on mobile and desktop, go responsive (Fluid widths  + media queries).

- See [this post about responsive apps](http://adioso.com/blog/2013/06/responsifying-adioso/)
- [Here is the RWD book](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design)
- [This post also has some good advice](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/12/building-a-responsive-web-application/)

Comment: Thanks, media queries + fluid widths look the way to go, just off the top of your head do you know if twitter bootstrap use media queries?

Comment: Yes, it [includes it by default](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive)